# How do I format a pendrive quickly, with a simple one-liner, from command line?

Tags: linux, fdisk

How do I repartition and format a pendrive quickly, with a simple one-liner, from command line?

I would like to do something like this:

```
$ format /dev/sdb
```

which would destroy the existing partitions, create only a single partition of type VFAT (W95 FAT32) and obviously this single partition must be ready for being used.

So, no matter what kind of experiment I did with the pendrive, no matter how many partitions it has, I would like to turn it back to a factory state.

Answer (score 0):

The solution below is available in my toolbox at: http://github.com/frgomes/bash-scripts

```
#!/bin/bash -eu

################################################
#                                              #
# DANGER ::: DANGER WILL ROBINSON ::: DANGER   #
#                                              #
# https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RG0ochx16Dg  #
#                                              #
# THIS SCRIPT CREATES A SINGLE FAT32 PARTITION #
#      ON THE DEVICE YOU PASS AS ARGUMENT      #
#                                              #
# *****  WITHOUT ASKING ANY CONFIRMATION ***** #
#                                              #
################################################

function format_layout {
  local device=${1:-/dev/null}
  local sectors=$(sudo blockdev --getsz ${device})
  local sectors=${sectors:-0}
  local sectors=$(echo ${sectors} - 2048 | bc)
  local id=$(openssl rand -hex 4)
  cat <<EOD
label: dos
label-id: 0x${id}
device: ${device}
unit: sectors
sector-size: 512

${device}1 : start=2048, size=${sectors}, type=0b
EOD
}

function format() {
  which bc >/dev/null || apt+ install bc
  sudo which sfdisk >/dev/null 2>&1 || apt+ install sfdisk
  local device=${1:-dev/null}
  format_layout ${device} | sudo sfdisk --wipe always ${device} && sudo mkfs.vfat ${device}1
}

format $*
```